# Questions about VAF4A regarding Issuing Authority and visitor stamps

Tags: visa, uk-visa, paperwork

We are filling in the VAF4A application form for family settlement for a spouse visa.

We came across a question related to past visas for the UK which asks who was the issuing authority.

My wife is Brazilian, so she does not need a visa to enter the UK for up to 6 months as a visitor.

For her visits, does the 6-month stamp count as the visa and, if so, who is the  issuing authority? Would it be border control?

She also had a Tier 4 student visa (to study an MSc.) which was issued in Rio de Janeiro, but it does not state the Issuing Authority on it. Who would be the issuing Authority?

Comment: The passport stamp constitutes *leave to enter.*  It is not a visa, so you don't need to include it here (I presume there is another place to mention that trip on the application).  I am not certain who the issuing authority is in the case of the tier 4 visa, but if I would be inclined to put "UK consulate, Rio de Janeiro."

Comment: That makes sense - its says RIO on the visa, but that seems to be location only, I guess we will make an educated guess on that one soon.

Comment: Indeed there is a Visa box and a Trips to the UK box on the form

Answer (score 1):

After Reading multiple forums looking for examples of people with the similar problem...

It seems in this case it would UKBA - RIO DE JANEIRO ( up until the date that UKBA became UKVI ) - However I can not categorically state if this is correct...

**Phoog** identified that a passport stamp is leave to enter and not a visa, which also makes sense within the remits of the form, considering that Brazilians do not need a Visa to travel to and visit the UK.